# Разбор слова "всюду"

Tags: морфология

Как морфологически разобрать наречие "всюду"?

Answer (score 2):

1. Часть речи - местоимённое наречие (особая форма наречия), так как, подобно местоимению, не называет признак, а только указывает на него, но, в отличие от местоимения, является неизменяемым словом.
2. Морфологические признаки:

   а) разряд по значению - определительное (признак от местоимения);
   б) неизменяемое (признак от наречия);
   в) степеней сравнения не имеет.
3. В предложении выполняет функции обстоятельства места.

Answer (score 1):

Всюду — местоименное  наречие, определительное, обстоятельство места.

Answer (score 1):

На  ЕГЭ и ГИА (многих интересует информация для экзамена в тестовой форме) - наречие. А в лингвистике разные точки зрения. Даже в учебнике под ред. Бабайцевой для средней школы - это местоимение. Определительное. Во всех остальных школьных учебниках - наречие.

Answer (score 0):

Наречие места, обозначает признак действия, неизменяемое, обстоятельство.